# Handling ties when ranking in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

Let's say I have a list of numbers that are already sorted as below

```
100
222
343
423
423
500
```

What I want is to create a rank field such that same values are assigned the same rank

```
100   1
222   2
343   3
423   4
423   4
500   5
```

I have been using the following piece of code to mimic a rank field

```
awk '{print $0, NR}' file
```

That gives me below,  but it's technically a rownumber.

```
100   1
222   2
343   3
423   4
423   5
500   6
```

How do I go about this? I am an absolute beginner in `bash` so would really appreciate if you could add a little explanation for learning sake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a job for awk:

```
$ awk '{if($0!=p)++r;print $0,r;p=$0}' file
```

Output:

```
100 1
222 2
343 3
423 4
423 4
500 5
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '{           # using awk
if($0!=p)          # if the value does not equal the previous value
    ++r            # increase the rank
print $0,r         # output value and rank
    p=$0           # store value for next round
}' file
```

Comment: If the field to be ranked is $6, is that how I would write it?

'{if($6!=p)++r;print $0,r;p=$6}'

Comment: Yes. And sorry for the delayed answer, but like you once said, @Gandalf, _expect me when you see me_. ;D

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'prev==$0{--count} {print $0,++count;prev=$1}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                 ##Starting awk code from here.
prev==$0              ##Checking condition if variable prev is equal to current line then do following.
{
  --count             ##Subtract count variable with 1 here.
}
{
  print $0,++count    ##Printing current line and variable count with increasing value of it.
  prev=$1             ##Setting value of prev to 1st field of current line.
}
' Input_file          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`

```
$ awk '{print $1, a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1]:++c}' file

100 1
222 2
343 3
423 4
423 4
500 5
```

where the file is not need to be sorted, for example after adding a new **423** at the end of the file

```
$ awk '{print $1, a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1]:++c}' file

100 1
222 2
343 3
423 4
423 4
500 5
423 4
```

increment the rank counter `a` for new value observed, otherwise use the registered value for the key.  since `c` is initialized to zero, pre-increment the value.  This will use the same **rank** value for the same key regardless or the position.

Comment: I like this approach too. Pretty intuitive